# Difference between java and JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, java, for-loop, difference

**Java Program**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args){        
    String str="XYZ ";     
    int i;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            str+= + i; 
            System.out.println(str);      
        }
    }
}
```

**//Java Output**

```
XYZ 0
XYZ 01
XYZ 012
XYZ 0123
XYZ 01234
```

**Javascript Program**

```
let str="XYZ ";
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
   str+=i+"<br>";
   document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=str;
}
```

**JavaScipt Output**

```
XYZ 0
1
2
3
4
```

**My doubt is:** What is the difference between for loop in Java and JavaScript. Can anyone explain the flow of **for loop** in Javascript?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=str;` This overwrites a variable each time. `System.out.println(str); ` This doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the JavaScript, you're setting the *entire contents* of the `demo1` container to the new string. At the end of the iterations, the element only contains the final value in the string.

In contrast, in the Java, you're logging and looking at the string on every iteration, instead of only the final value.

If you append new HTML markup in the JavaScript instead of overwriting what's previously in the container, you'll see the same output:

```js
let str = "XYZ ";
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  str += i;
  demo1.innerHTML += str + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<pre id="demo1"></pre>
```

Or, to change the Java to show what the original JavaScript does (sans the newlines), only examine the final string:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    str += + i;
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you're not including the newlines at the end of the string concatenations in the Java. So if you wanted to match the JS, it would be:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){        
    String str="XYZ ";     
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        str += + i + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Where the "**\n**" is the equivalent of the **BR** linebreak. Also, as others have mentioned, you are viewing the results differently, **println** appends newline each time it is called, hence the **ln**.

Output:

```
> java -cp . HelloWorld
XYZ 0
1
2
3
4
```

Threw me for a loop for a second there, thought there was something about for loops I was missing! They're acting the same it's just the inclusion of the linebreak on JS side, not on Java side.